# How to apply a function to every element in a list using Linq in C# like the method reduce() in python?

Tags: c#, python, linq

How to apply a function to every element in a list using Linq in C# like the method reduce() in python?

Comment: by `function` do you mean `event`? what is in the collection? what are you trying to do against this collection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [this reduce function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce), the equivalent in C# and LINQ is [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx).

Quick example:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(5, 3); // [5, 6, 7]
Console.WriteLine("Aggregation: {0}", list.Aggregate((a, b) => (a + b)));
// Result is "Aggregation: 18"
```

Answer (score 2):

Enumerable.Aggregate is your answer. reduce(function, list, seed) ==> list.Aggregate(seed, function). In addition, there are many predefined "aggregates", like Sum, Min, Max, Average, etc. You should use Aggregate only when the aggregator is not built-in.